Reduce the height of OutlinedTextField with multi-line enabled
I'm migrating my app from xml(Material 1) to Jetpack Compose(Material 3), the built-in OutlinedTextField has a fixed height of 56dp, which is too large. It can't be changed, so I'm trying to implement with BasicTextField.

There are some posts talking about using .height(36.dp), but it doesn't work with multi-line content, when the height is fixed, it will no longer expand vertically when pressing RETURN.
This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work:
BasicTextField(
    modifier = modifier
        // .height(36.dp) // this doesn't work for multi-line
        .heightIn(min = 36.dp) // it has no effect
        .defaultMinSize(
            minWidth = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
            minHeight = 36.dp, // no effect either
        )
    ,
    decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
        OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
            // the padding of the text within the box
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp, 10.dp), 
//...

How to reduce the height, for example to 36.dp? And when user press RETURN to generate new lines, the vertical size should also increase.

I can't get your requirement. What is the issue and what you want to improve?

@AjayChandran Sorry, I have updated the question, my question is: how to reduce the height to 40dp without breaking any other feature.

Have you tried using requiredHeightIn() extension?

@AjayChandran Not working, no difference with or without .requiredHeightIn(36.dp), .requiredHeightIn(36.dp, 36.dp) has same behavior as .height(36.dp)

If that is the case, then avoid setting height in modifier. Just set the respective content padding in decoration box and it will work.
